# Programmatically Selecting CRS in QGIS using Python?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

When you run the following Python code in the Python Console of QGIS 2.4,

```
uri = "file:///C:/data.csv?type=csv&xField=lng&yField=lat&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Points', "delimitedtext")
```

you are presented with the Coordinate Reference System Selector popup window as shown below.

Is there a way to **programmatically** select a CRS instead of having a user manually select it?

[image]

---

Tried the following but the CRS Selector dialog window still appears.

```
uri = "file:///C:/data.csv?type=csv&xField=lng&yField=lat&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Points', "delimitedtext")
vlayer.setCrs( QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId) )
```

Comment: Theres setCoordinateSystem(...) which can be called on a vector layer object, but that probably doesnt stop the dialog from showing. http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a511bf3d6ef9817f6972b57f9f6655142

Comment: You could use the option "Use project CRS" from Options->CRS->CRS for new layers. Also you could change that settings by code before to call ```QgsVectorLayer``` accessing to the ```QSettings``` class

Comment: @til_b Tried your suggestion `vlayer.setCrs( QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId) )` and the dialog window still appears. I think its because `.setCRS()` is called after `QgsVectorLayer()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you can add the item to define the crs string to the URI like `&crs=EPSG:4326`.

Your code should look as follows:

```py
uri = "file:///C:/data.csv?type=csv&xField=lng&yField=lat&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no&crs=EPSG:4326"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Points', "delimitedtext")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

As said above, you have an alternative by accesing to the settings of QGIS, the follow snippet does what I suggest before and uses the CRS defined in your project:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings

s = QSettings()
## possible values are: prompt, useProject, useGlobal
s.setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useProject")

## here your code ##
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful if you change the QSettings as mentionned above, you should restore the default value after your process. I would really hate a plugin if this plugin is changing my preferences in the background.

You should do something like that :

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings

s = QSettings()
# possible values are: prompt, useProject, useGlobal
default_value = s.value("/Projections/defaultBehaviour")
s.setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useProject")

# here, add your layer to the mapcanvas

s.setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", default_value)
```

Comment: For the records, to be extra-safe: put the second `setValue` into a `finally:` block while everything starting from the first `setValue` call is in the preceding `try:` block.