# Create a layer in PyQgis with the same CRS as another

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I want to create a layer which use the same CRS as another layer I already have in the project. The idea is to avoid the CRS dialog.

I tried the things in this link:
[How to define layer's CRS and avoid the CRS dialog in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136378/how-to-define-layers-crs-and-avoid-the-crs-dialog-in-pyqgis)

But it doesn't work because as soon as I create the layer the program launches the dialog.

```
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer("shapefile_path", "Layer_name", "ogr")

#Use loaded layer as active layer to set the CRS
myLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
myLayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))
```

I tried something like

```
crs = originalLayer().crs().authid()
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "auxlayer", "memory")
layer2.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs))
```

And it works but only after the dialog appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
crs = originalLayer.crs().authid() # without () after originalLayer
layer2 = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs={0}".format(crs), "auxlayer", "memory")
```