# How to remove a pop-up window with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

In my standalone PyQGIS script, at one moment the QGIS CRS window pops-up to select a CRS. I want to add some code to remove the pop-up again when it appears.

I couldn't find anything helpful in the docs yet. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136439/4972) or the other answers in that thread?