# PyQGIS writeAsVectorFormat: How to properly set the coordinate reference system?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm exporting xml-data files to geopackage, which seems to work. However, the coordinate reference system is not included in the xml-data, but I know it is EPSG:25832.
How can I set the CRS system when writing the layer to file with the  QGSVectorFileWriter?

My code looks like this. :

```
dlayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, 'layer_name', 'ogr')
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(dlayer, outputFilename, "utf-8", dlayer.crs() , "GPKG")
```

Here I use the CRS from the XML-file, which doesn't have one
. How can I set the CRS to EPSG:25832 ?
I did try already to include the crs as string, but this didn't work and I created a QgsReferenceObject, but his didn't throw any errors but it didn't set the CRS.

Comment: Seems like `QgsVectorFileWriter` has no method do define a CRS, but you can simply use `.setCrs()` before for `QgsVectorLayer`'s. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136378/defining-layer-crs-and-avoiding-crs-dialog-in-pyqgis for example.

Comment: Oh boy, you don't know how much this helped me! Thank you @MrXsquared

Comment: @Taras I did try your solution beforehand, and unfortunately it didn't work for my data. However, I think I specified the CRS with lower cases (so:```epsg:25832```). Maybe this matters.

Comment: It is True. I think it really may have sth to do with the structure of the data (it is xml).

Comment: The `destCRS` parameter is use to **reproject** the data from current crs. I guess your problem is that your source layer (your xml loaded in a `QgsVectorLayer`) does not have any crs associated. QGIS seems to consider your layer as valid but I'm pretty sure it's not. Consequently, QGIS is not able to reproject from nothing to `EPSG:25832` This also explain that the solution you found (setting the crs on the layer) works. Then you say to QGIS reproject my `EPSG:25832` layer to `EPSG:25832` which basically does nothing.

Comment: @YoLecomte That sounds very valid! Thanks for the explanation! In QGIS it also didn't have a valid CRS, I had to set it manually.

Comment: @i.i.k. yes that make sense.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is actually from the comment of @MrXsquared.

The solution was, to first correct the CRS of the input layer, and then take that CRS as input for the QGsVectorFileWriter. The code:

```
# create QgsVectorLayer -object            
dlayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, 'layer_name', 'ogr')

# Set the CRS for the object 
crs = dlayer.crs()
crs.createFromId(25832)
dlayer.setCrs(crs)

# Then take the CRS as input for the export
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(dlayer, outputFilename, "utf-8", dlayer.crs(), "GPKG")
```